# C# работа с DBF от FoxPRO 2.0

Tags: c#, dbf

В общем такая лабораторная работа:
Есть файл DB.DBF от FoxPRO 2.0. Нужно на C# Windows Form сделать элемент DataGridView и вывести в него все данные из этой бд. Так же реализовать кнопки редактирования, добавления и удаления записей в этой БД и поиск по всем столбцам.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace DBF_User
{
    public partial class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form()
        {
            this.Conn = new OdbcConnection();
            Conn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase  Driver (*.dbf)};" + "SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;" + "Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;" + "BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
        }

        private OdbcConnection Conn = null;

        public DataTable Execute(string Command)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = null;
            if (Conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Conn.Open();
                    dataTable = new DataTable();
                    OdbcCommand oCmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
                    oCmd.CommandText = Command;
                    dataTable.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
                    Conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }
            return dataTable;
        }

        public DataTable GetAll(string DB_path)
        {
            return Execute("SELECT * FROM " + DB_path);
        }

        private void ButtonOpenDBF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBF_User DBFU = new DBF_User();                                 // Тут ругается "DBF_User является пространством имен, но используется как тип"
            DataGridViewDBF.DataSource = DBFU.GetAll(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "DB.dbf");
        }
    }
}
```

Код не запускается, возникает ошибка "DBF_User является пространством имен, но используется как тип". Как исправить эту ошибку? Ну и может кто уже подобное реализовывал и может рассказать как работать с данной БД через C#, редактировать, сохранять и удалять записи в ней?

Comment: Правильно ругается, т.к. `namespace DBF_User`, а потом `DBF_User DBFU = new DBF_User();`

Comment: @Bulson ну если переименовать namespace то вообще ничего не работает

Comment: А тут переименованием не поможешь, потому как не понятно где у вас метод `GetAll()` и почему вы не вызываете метод Execute(), который как раз и должен работать с базой.

Comment: @Bulson этот код нашел как пример в интернете, а он не рабочий оказывается, эх.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string FilePath = Application.StartupPath;
string DBF_FileName = "DB.DBF";

            OleDbConnection Conn;
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter;
            DataSet dataSet;
            OleDbCommand oleDbCommand;
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            string connetionString = null;
            try
            {
                connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + "; Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
                Conn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
                Conn.Open();
                string Sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DBF_FileName;
                oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, Conn);
                oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
                dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            }
            catch
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Не найден файл Базы Данных 'DB.DBF'", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                //Application.Exit();
            }
```